# Nginx ssl with a custom port configuration fails

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have the following nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen 4050;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name url ww.url;

    location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:6091;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }



   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
   include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

THe above works on http that is after accessing `http://domain:4050` but fails when i access the same with https that is via `https://domain:4050`

What am i missing on this to make it work with https on the port 4050.

Comment: what is the error that you get ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make it work with https, you need to change `listen 4050;`  to `listen 4050 ssl;`. But then you will not be able to use it with http.

> You cant use the same port for both HTTP and HTTPS